# CSS character encoding

Tags: css, encoding

According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset.en.php), CSS can set its character encoding by `@charset` in the first line, is it valid to to say that I should put `@charset "UTF-8"` in every CSS i made, even it only contains ASCII characters?

Will there be any performance penalty after I declare it using UTF-8 ?

*p.s. I can't think of a way to test it out.*

Comment: I would like this cleared up too definitely, but if you have caching enabled, it should just cache the whole file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not valid to say so, as an unqualified statement. If your file contains only ASCII characters, it is very likely that its character encoding is ASCII compatible (EBCDIC is not much used there days), so the rule would be harmless, but also pointless as long as the file keeps being ASCII-only.

What matters is what happens when a non-ASCII character gets inserted into the CSS file, for whatever reason. It could be, for example, a innocent-look smart quote (”) inserted when editing the file with a program that produces smart quotes. It is more likely that the smart quote gets inserted in windows-1252 encoding than in UTF-8 encoding. So if the file has the `@charset "UTF-8"` rule, it probably becomes a bit more difficult to analyze the problem.

If, on the other hand, you know that your CSS file will be edited using software that uses UTF-8 encoding by default, then it is OK to declare it as UTF-8 encoded even if it only contains ASCII characters. For example, if you some day edit the file and add a declaration like `content: "“foo”"`, you might forget to add the `@charset` rule.

There is no overhead in declaring the encoding as UTF-8. If the data contains ASCII characters only, any decent routine that reads UTF-8 will process the characters as fast as simple reading of ASCII. A routine that reads a UTF-8 bytestream will *have* to first check whether the byte is in the ASCII range and take it as standing for an ASCII character if it is.